# What's the word to use for "confidential", as in a company report?

Tags: word-choice, business-japanese

I'm preparing a sales presentation; it contains some company data and I want to indicate that the entire presentation is confidential.  In English, this would likely be accomplished by stamping the corner with "confidential".

What's the best word to use in Japanese for a similar meaning?  I've seen this somewhere in my old company, but I forgot... here are the candidates I know of, but the one I think I've seen before isn't there, I'm having trouble finding something where I say "aha that's it".

- 内緒 (ないしょ)  -- more used as in "private", like a small secret between a few people
- 秘密 (ひみつ  -- "secret", but not sure if this is the appropriate word
- 機密 (きみつ）-- don't understand how this is different than 秘密
- 親展 (しんてん) -- you see this on envelopes of letters, but that's about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a special symbol printed/stamped on secret documents, which is in red color with the character `秘` circled. They look like [this](http://www.google.co.jp/search?&q=%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E7%A7%98&oe=utf-8&hl=ja&tbm=isch). Because of this symbol, secrets are usually abbreviated as `マル秘{ひ}`. Some Japanese font encodings even have this as one of their characters.

For corporate documents, I think the most orthodox word is `社{しゃ}外{がい}秘{ひ}` 'to be kept secret from company outsiders', for which [stamps](http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E7%A4%BE%E5%A4%96%E7%A7%98&hl=ja&tbm=isch) also exist.

Comment: The マル秘 symbol also exists in Unicode as [U+3299](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3299/index.htm).

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Thanks, I wasn't sure how popular it was. I worried that it might be a 外字, but seems no need of worry.

Comment: Here is the character: ㊙ Depending on browser font settings, it may not appear, but if you see the character described, then you can copy and paste it. :)

Comment: @sawa: By the way, I edited your answer because "to be kept secret outside the company" the company would mean that everyone outside the company knows the secret, but that the people inside the company don't know it. Which would be a very strange document for a company to have ;). The more correct way to express it in English would be "kept secret *within* the company" (inside it is known, outside it is not). Which is interesting, because now that I look at the kanji and consider your translation, 秘{ひ} would seem to imply "keep secret *from* others", not just "secret".

Comment: To support Dave M G’s interpretation of 秘, some people use the word “社内秘” for documents which must be kept secret within some department in a company (“Keep this secret from other people in the company”).

Comment: @DaveMG Interesting point, but doesn't that depend on how you parse it? Using `outside/within the company` as adverbial: `[keep it secret] outside the company` vs. adjectival: `keep it [secret within the company]`. I intended the former, but you seem to be intending the latter.

Comment: @DaveMG Can you suggest a English translation that reflects `外` 'outside' used in the Japanese word? That will be a better literal translation.

Comment: @sawa: Agreed - since 外 appears in the original Japanese, the focus should be on who the secret is kept from. I think "to be kept secret from company outsiders" is maybe the best. If you agree that it is suitable, then I'll leave it to you to edit. Or, if you think it's still not right for some reason, let me know.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Interesting that 秘 can be used for both 社内秘 and 社外秘 in that way. Is it accurate to say 秘 always focuses on who the secret is kept *from*? Or is it sometimes just used to mean a secret in general? With 極秘情報, it seems to just mean there is "top secret information", but doesn't say who it is secret from.

Comment: @DaveMG: I do not know the answer.  Clearly 秘 is not always used with any party, but if it is used with one party (such as 社内 or 社外), it seems that it means that the secret is kept _from_ the mentioned party, as far as I can think of right now.  However, I am not confident enough to conclude that this is always the case.

Answer (score 8):

Generally in Japanese you write 「XXX取扱」to indicate you request special or sensitive handling of the materials in question.

There are some variations you could use. Here are a couple I know / looked up with approximate English equivalents.

1. 秘密情報取扱 (ひみつじょうほうとりあつかい) - [Handle as] secret or private information
2. 機密情報取扱 (きみつじょうほうとりあつかい) - [Handle as] confidential information
3. 厳密情報取扱 (げんみつじょうほうとりあつかい) - [Handle as] **strictly** confidential information

Avoid these ones though, unless you're in the military or government:

1. 最高秘密情報 (さいこうひみつじょうほう) - top secret information
2. 極秘情報 (ごくひじょうほう) - classified information

There are many others that would be more appropriate to use in an email, a letter or a report such as:

1. 内申 (ないしん) - confidential (internal/unofficial) report
2. 秘録 (ひろく) - confidential record

Comment: You may say `...扱い`, but `...取(り)扱(い)` sounds awkward. I have never heard of a word `厳密情報`.